# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) when testing with enzyme mount

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing a wrapper component which renders its children using children props. The problem is that in the test file, when I set the wrapper, it works fine. But when I clone the children props in component, I get the following error:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for 
built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but 
got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the 
file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

This happens only when using mount and not shallow, I want this to work with mount.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {
       const { someProps, someOtherProps, anotherProp } = this.props;

        return (
            <ParentWrapper someInfo={someProps} >
                <One someOtherProps={someOtherProps} />
                <Two  anotherProp={anotherProp} />
            </ParentWrapper>
        );
    }
}
```

ParentWrapper:

```
class ParentWrapper extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {children, somethin} = this.props;
        const clonedChildren = React.cloneElement(children, R.merge(children.props, { somethin }));

        return (
            <div>
                {clonedChildren}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

testfile:

```
 const Parent = require('parent');
 panel = mount(<Parent {...defaultProps} />);
```

Comment: It happens when you accidentally omitted your `export` statement or `exporting` wrong component name. I recommend you to check out your `export` statements.

Comment: I have checked my export and the way that i'm doing it seems fine. The weird thing is that when I don't clone the children in ParentWrapper and use children instead of clonedChildren, then everything works fine. Or if I use shallow instead of mount from enzyme that also works fine.

Comment: Having the same issue :(

Comment: Having the same issue, things work fine with enzyme but throws error with mount

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this as well.  Most other similar answers on SO refer to proper import/exports, but it works fine when I use `shallow()`, which implies it's not the import/export.

Ultimately I found that I had slightly mismatching versions of `react` and `react-dom`.  (Reminder, since I needed it, delete the existing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` to make sure you actually are pulling the updated modules).  This fixed it for me.